# Is it possible to get the type of uninitialized variable in Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, dynamic, types

The task was meant to be quite simple: I needed to initialize variable with **new** keyword dynamically, depending on it's type. For example:

```
public var object:Sprite;

...

object = new Sprite();
```

In this case type is *Sprite*, but it could be anything and a method which actually instantiates it with *new*, doesn't know with what type it was declared. Of course I could store type (or class name) in string variable and instantiate object with it. But I just wonder if I could get that type info from the object itself, 'cause it's declared in a class and logically thinking it's type info might be stored somewhere and be retrievable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, but the variable must be public (or have accessor methods), and you need its name as a String:

Use [describeType()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) to get an XML Description of your class, then get accessors and variables as XMLList, iterate until you find your variable's name, and get the class by calling [getDefinitionByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29).  Here's an example:

```
var className : String = "";
var type:XML = describeType (this);
var variables:XMLList = type..variable;
for each (var variable:XML in variables) {
    if (variable.@name == myVariableName) {
        className = variable.@type;
        break;
    }
}
if (className == "") {
    var accessors:XMLList = type..accessor;
    for each (var accessor:XML in accessors) {
        if (accessor.@name == myVariableName) {
            className = accessor.@type;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (className=="") {
    trace ("no such variable");
    return;
}
var ClassReference : Class = getDefinitionByName( className.replace ("::", ".") ) as Class;
myVariable = new ClassReference( );
```

Comment: By the way, is there any info of how big the performance penalty for this might be?

Comment: Yeah, it's substantial, unfortunately.  You can improve performance by keeping a hash table with the accessors and variables of the types you have already described once, so you only have to do the XMLList iterations from the second time on.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to "reply" to an answer, otherwise I would add this to the current top answer.

If you have a list of known types that the object could be, you could test against those types using [typeof](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#typeof).

```
switch(typeof unknownVar)
{
   case typeof Function:
       unknownVar = new Function();
       break;
   case typeof String:
       unknownVar = "Bruce Lee";
       break;
   case typeof Number:
       unknownVar = 3.14;
       break;
   default:
       trace(typeof unknownVar);  // This is not normally helpful...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In short no, you can't get the type of an uninitialised variable.

Sounds like this is kind of a factory pattern implementation. Your best bet is to pass a reference of the Class to the method

method:

```
public function create(class:Class) : void
{
   return new class();
}
```

calling code:

```
public var object:Sprite;

...

object = createObject(Sprite)
```

Comment: You're wrong, and your creation method doesn't solve the problem - you would still need the class type to instantiate.

Comment: @weltraumpirat - Fair shout on the reflection, although it's probably a bit long winded given ActionScript's limited reflection capabilities.  My answer is more of a different approach given that he has a method that instantiates an object of varying type.

Comment: Yes, it does, but you pass the class type as an argument.  The question was how to instantiate the variable if you don't know the type - so your solution really doesn't solve the problem at all.